# Need help to output vba excel function as date value

Tags: javascript, vba, excel, date

this is my function:

```
function foo() as date
   foo = "08/15/2015"
end function
```

is return 42231 instead of "8/15/2015"
if I change the function to below code:

```
function foo()
   foo = format("08/15/2015", "dd/mm/yyyy")
end function
```

then it works, but I am unable to format the output to any other type such as longdate or short date, or manually change it to "dd/mm/yyyy".
Do we have any solution that a vba function can output a date value, in the date format, and the output can be formatted to another type manually by user? Example: I have the ouput "8/15/2015", and I can manually format it to "Aug/15/2015"

Comment: You are calling it from a formula? If so, have you tried formatting the formula as date?

Comment: Yes. I call it from a formula. Yes. I can format it. But what I want is: the function return a date value, in the date format, and the output can be further formatted.

Answer (score 3):

A *UDF* can only return a value to a cell, not format that cell.  So:

```
Public Function foo() As Date
    foo = DateSerial(2015, 8, 15)
End Function
```

will display:

[image]

only if you format it that way.

**NOTE:**

This is true of *UDF*s.  If you manually enter:

```
=TODAY()
```

in a cell, Excel will format the cell to a date format by itself.

Comment: Might be worth adding that Excel stores dates as a number, hence the 42231 value, but then displays them in the format you set.

Comment: @Gary's Student: Noted that UDF can return values only and not format. Your function also return date in a number format in my Excel 2007. In short, now I understand that my request is not possible to meet in VBA: **A function, return a date value, in a date pre-formatted (i.e: dd/mm/yyyy), and then can further be formatted by excel user.**